# Inner Join returning redundant data and not the expected data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join, distinct

I have below query -

```
 SELECT CP.PostID,CP.SectionID                              
     FROM NewsLetter NW  
     inner Join MapNewsletterPosts as MM on NW.ID = MM.ID        
     inner join CSPosts as CP with (nolock) on MM.PostID = CP.PostID       
     inner join PostStatus PS on PS.Postid=CP.PostId      
     WHERE  
     NW.NewsletterDate = '2015-07-06' 
     and CP.IsApproved =1                                           
     ANd PS.StatusId =7      
     AND CP.SectionID NOT IN (92,227)        
     AND NW.SectionID = 95
     ORDER BY MM.Newslettersortorder
```

Above query returns correct result as show below -

[image]

Now, When i add one more join to the above query -

```
SELECT CP.PostID,CP.SectionID                                
     FROM NewsLetter NW    
     inner Join MapNewsletterPosts as MM on NW.ID = MM.ID          
     inner join CSPosts as CP with (nolock) on MM.PostID = CP.PostID         
     inner join PostStatus PS on PS.Postid=CP.PostId      
     INNER JOIN NewsletterDetails ND ON ND.NewsletterDate = NW.NewsletterDate AND ND.IncludeInArticles=1 <<--added extra JOIN   
     WHERE    
     NW.NewsletterDate = '2015-07-06'   
     and CP.IsApproved =1                                             
     ANd PS.StatusId =7        
     AND CP.SectionID NOT IN (92,227)          
     AND NW.SectionID = 95  
     ORDER BY MM.Newslettersortorder
```

It results in redundant data as shown below -

[image]
    What changes i need to make in a query to return proper results [distinct].
Thanks in advance...!!

Comment: http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the `ON` condition with `ND.PostId =CP.PostID`

try this -

```
SELECT CP.PostID,CP.SectionID                                
     FROM NewsLetter NW    
     inner Join MapNewsletterPosts as MM on NW.ID = MM.ID          
     inner join CSPosts as CP with (nolock) on MM.PostID = CP.PostID         
     inner join PostStatus PS on PS.Postid=CP.PostId      
     INNER JOIN NewsletterDetails ND ON ND.PostId =CP.PostID AND ND.IncludeInArticles=1    
     WHERE    
     NW.NewsletterDate = '2015-07-06'   
     and CP.IsApproved =1                                             
     ANd PS.StatusId =7        
     AND CP.SectionID NOT IN (92,227)          
     AND NW.SectionID = 95  
     ORDER BY MM.Newslettersortorder
```

Answer (score 4):

You can replace the extra join with `EXISTS()` :

```
 SELECT CP.PostID,CP.SectionID                              
 FROM NewsLetter NW  
 inner Join MapNewsletterPosts as MM on NW.ID = MM.ID        
 inner join CSPosts as CP with (nolock) on MM.PostID = CP.PostID       
 inner join PostStatus PS on PS.Postid=CP.PostId      
 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM NewsletterDetails nd
              WHERE ND.NewsletterDate = NW.NewsletterDate AND ND.IncludeInArticles=1)
      AND NW.NewsletterDate = '2015-07-06' 
      and CP.IsApproved =1                                           
      ANd PS.StatusId =7      
      AND CP.SectionID NOT IN (92,227)        
      AND NW.SectionID = 95
 ORDER BY MM.Newslettersortorder
```

This happens due to more then 1 row with the same `NewsletterDate` in the extra table, exists will eliminate this and you will no longer need to use `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` also.

**EDIT:** If you want only those records that a record with `IncludeInArticles=0` doesn't exists for them, then use this:

```
 SELECT CP.PostID,CP.SectionID                              
 FROM NewsLetter NW  
 inner Join MapNewsletterPosts as MM on NW.ID = MM.ID        
 inner join CSPosts as CP with (nolock) on MM.PostID = CP.PostID       
 inner join PostStatus PS on PS.Postid=CP.PostId      
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM NewsletterDetails nd
                  WHERE ND.NewsletterDate = NW.NewsletterDate AND ND.IncludeInArticles=0)
      AND NW.NewsletterDate = '2015-07-06' 
      and CP.IsApproved =1                                           
      ANd PS.StatusId =7      
      AND CP.SectionID NOT IN (92,227)        
      AND NW.SectionID = 95
 ORDER BY MM.Newslettersortorder
```

**EDIT:** Its hard to understand what exactly you want! I'm guessing that you want the records that have `IncludeInArticles = 1` and doesn't have `IncludeInArticles=0` ? Right now it's the only option left:

```
 SELECT CP.PostID,CP.SectionID                              
 FROM NewsLetter NW  
 inner Join MapNewsletterPosts as MM on NW.ID = MM.ID        
 inner join CSPosts as CP with (nolock) on MM.PostID = CP.PostID       
 inner join PostStatus PS on PS.Postid=CP.PostId      
 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM NewsletterDetails nd
              WHERE ND.NewsletterDate = NW.NewsletterDate AND ND.IncludeInArticles=1)
   AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM NewsletterDetails nd
                  WHERE ND.NewsletterDate = NW.NewsletterDate AND ND.IncludeInArticles=0)
      AND NW.NewsletterDate = '2015-07-06' 
      and CP.IsApproved =1                                           
      ANd PS.StatusId =7      
      AND CP.SectionID NOT IN (92,227)        
      AND NW.SectionID = 95
 ORDER BY MM.Newslettersortorder
```

Comment: I have checked your query but the condition `ND.IncludeInArticles=1` is not working it is returning the rows which has `ND.IncludeInArticles=0` as well

Comment: Wait a second, you want only the rows where a row with `ND.IncludeInArticles=0` doesn't exists? @PranavBilurkar

Comment: miss-understanding i want the rows which has `ND.IncludeInArticles=1`

Comment: @Pranav Bilurkar: I think you need to better explain the ***intent*** of the join with `NewsletterDetails`. It's not clear what you are trying to accomplish with it, thus the varying answers.

Comment: @PranavBilurkar Then this query should work! Its possible that there are both records with `ND.IncludeInArticles=1` and `ND.IncludeInArticles=0` , so that's why its confusing

Comment: your first query is right but what i am saying is that despite of giving the condition `ND.IncludeInArticles=1` the query is returning the PostID which has `ND.IncludeInArticles=0`.

Comment: But, In the `NewsletterDetails` there are unique `postID`

Comment: But you are joining by dates, not by id. I think you need to combine both exists and not exists together, a few minutes and I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

What happens is your final inner join will have multiple rows of data per PostID.

The easiest way to get back to the first set of results would be add the distinct modifier to the select:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CP.PostID,CP.SectionID
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason that this is happening is that you'll have multiple rows of data in NewsLetterDetails. Try pulling in one of the fields from this table into your query to see what I mean.

```
 SELECT 
     CP.PostID
     ,CP.SectionID 
     ,ND.*                            
 FROM NewsLetter NW    
 INNER JOIN MapNewsletterPosts as MM 
     ON NW.ID = MM.ID          
 INNER JOIN CSPosts as CP with (nolock) 
     ON MM.PostID = CP.PostID         
 INNER JOIN PostStatus PS 
     ON PS.Postid=CP.PostId      
 INNER JOIN NewsletterDetails ND 
     ON ND.NewsletterDate = NW.NewsletterDate 
     AND ND.IncludeInArticles=1    
 WHERE NW.NewsletterDate = '2015-07-06'   
     AND CP.IsApproved =1                                             
     AND PS.StatusId =7        
     AND CP.SectionID NOT IN (92,227)          
     AND NW.SectionID = 95  
 ORDER BY MM.Newslettersortorder
```

If you just want a unique list like you had before do this;

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
     CP.PostID
     ,CP.SectionID 
 FROM NewsLetter NW    
 INNER JOIN MapNewsletterPosts as MM 
     ON NW.ID = MM.ID          
 INNER JOIN CSPosts as CP with (nolock) 
     ON MM.PostID = CP.PostID         
 INNER JOIN PostStatus PS 
     ON PS.Postid=CP.PostId      
 INNER JOIN NewsletterDetails ND 
     ON ND.NewsletterDate = NW.NewsletterDate 
     AND ND.IncludeInArticles=1    
 WHERE NW.NewsletterDate = '2015-07-06'   
     AND CP.IsApproved =1                                             
     AND PS.StatusId =7        
     AND CP.SectionID NOT IN (92,227)          
     AND NW.SectionID = 95  
 ORDER BY MM.Newslettersortorder
```

Comment: But, i dont want to select anything from NewsletterDetails...the query should only return `PostID` and `SectionID`

Comment: I created the first query to explain why you're seeing data that you're not expecting. Use the second query in my answer if you just want a distinct list.

Comment: ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified. - second query

Comment: do you need to order by that field? I can't see any reason for that to be in there.

Comment: Sounds like @sagi has the answer you're after, it's a good way of dealing with it.